# Exact Error when Calculating $\int \ln x dx$ using trapezium rule

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series

I want to find the sum of the series
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left( \int_k^{k+1} \ln x dx-\frac12 (\ln(k+1)+\ln k)\right).
$$
I can prove it to be convergent, but wolframalpha gives the exact value $1-\frac12(\ln 2+\ln \pi)$. Where does it come from? Stiring's formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Just for your curiosity.*

It is possible to compute exactly the partial sums
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\left( \int_k^{k+1} \ln x dx-\frac12 \Big(\ln(k+1)+\ln (k)\Big)\right)$$

The formula is a bit complex but using asymptotics
$$S_n=\left(1-\frac{1}{2} \log (2 \pi )\right)-\frac{1}{12 n}+\frac{1}{12
   n^2}-\frac{29}{360 n^3}+\frac{3}{40 n^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$$

Using it for $n=10$, the exact value is
$$S_{10}=\log \left(\frac{25937424601 \sqrt{11}}{3628800}\right)-10 \approx 0.0734878$$ while the above truncated series would give
$$S_{10}\sim \frac{3572737}{3600000}-\frac{1}{2} \log (2 \pi )\approx       0.0734884$$

**Edit**

Suppose that you want to know the value of $n$ such that
$$\Delta_n=\Big|S_n-\left(1-\frac{1}{2} \log (2 \pi )\right)\Big|=\epsilon$$ Transforming the series into a Padé approximant, you just need to solve
$$\frac{5 (n+1)}{60 n^2+120n+62}=\epsilon\implies n=\Big\lceil\frac{ \sqrt{5(5-96 \epsilon ^2)}+5-120 \epsilon }{120 \epsilon }\Big\rceil$$

For $\epsilon=10^{-3}$, this approximate formula would give $n=83$. Checking
$$\Delta_{82}=0.001004 \quad \text{(not OK)} \quad \text{while} \qquad \Delta_{83}=0.000992\quad \text{(OK)} $$

Comment: So an exact formula for $S_n$ exists but is too long to write down here?

Comment: @Jethro. It is not long but it involves special functions that you will hear abour later. This is why I did not write it.

Comment: Could you give a reference for or write down that formula? Maybe I know it:) Thanks

Comment: @Jethro. Enjoy the formula $$S_n=\zeta ^{(1,0)}(-1,n+2)+\log (A)-\log (H(n))-n-\frac{1}{2} \log (\Gamma
   (n+1))-\frac{1}{2} \log (\Gamma (n+2))-\frac{1}{12}$$ where appear the derivative of zeta function, Glaisher constant and the hyperfactorial function.

Comment: Thank you. That's phenomenal:)

Answer (score 0):

Evaluating the integral term by term, it is easy to show that the series is
$$
\sum ((r+\frac12)(\ln (r+1)-\ln r)-1)
$$
Now, canceling term by term to get rid of the $r+\frac12$ factor, writing $\sum_{k=1}^n\ln k=\ln (n!)$, the series equals to
$$
\lim_{r\to \infty} \ln \frac{(r+1)^{r+\frac12}}{e^r r!}.
$$
Using stirling's approximation, this limit is $e/\sqrt{2\pi}$, hence the result.